# Getting static_map in amcl does not work

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Yesterday I installed the latest updates (including the gazebo and navigation stacks). Since then, the amcl does not work anymore. I traced the problem back to the service call AMCL makes to the map_server to get the map.

This is the code (it is the standard code)
link:[amcl_node.cpp](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/amcl/html/amcl__node_8cpp_source.html) line 495

The call is made (AMCL printing: Request for map failed; trying again...), but it never reaches the map_server service. I tried to call it manually via a terminal ( rosservice call static_map ) and then the service is carried out correctly and a response is sent.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and ros-electric.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28390/getting-static_map-in-amcl-does-not-work/) by [Laurie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1472/laurie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2012-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was in the namespacing of the service. My amcl node ran in another namespace ("/turtlebot") then the map_server ("/"). It will work if both nodes run in the same namespace.

---

Originally posted by [Laurie](https://answers.ros.org/users/1472/laurie/) with karma: 103 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1